# Conflicting info about installed macOS version in App store

Tags: macos, imac, install, mac-appstore

Machine has version 10.9.5 installed but the app store thinks that version 10.12.6 is installed.

How do I update to the latest version?
[image: screen shot showing version info]

Comment: Check your applications folder and see if the installer has been downloaded. "Install macOS Sierra.app". Also check if your machine is compatible: https://support.apple.com/kb/sp742

Answer (score 2):

Go to the **Purchased** tab and click the `Download` button next to macOS Sierra in the App Store.